# How to store in database the value in select tag after submitting

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

I have a select tag command in html/php. After the user select an option and submits the form, I want the value of it to be stored in my sql database. I have a separate file of php for the select tag and for storing the database.

This is select tag command in my form:

```
<form name="stdntdetails" action="submit_stdntdetails.php" method="post">
    <select>
        <option value="IT">Information Technology</option>
        <option value="IS">Information System</option>
        <option value="CS">Computer Science</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

I don't know what to put in my submit_stdntdetails.php

Comment: put the name of you select tag first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form name="stdntdetails" action="submit_stdntdetails.php" method="post">
    <select name="department">
        <option value="IT">Information Technology</option>
        <option value="IS">Information System</option>
        <option value="CS">Computer Science</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

In submit_stdntdetails.php

```
<?php
include_once('connectdb.php');
if(isset($_POST['department'])){
$department=$_POST['department'];
$sql=mysql_query("insert into tbl_name(department) values('$department')");
}
?>
```

Comment: The $department being a varchar value should be in single quotes. -1 for that

Comment: The query is wide open to SQL injection. Plus, mysql_query is deprecated and will be removed from PHP eventually.

Comment: Thanks punitha subramani v and Smruti Singh, it worked!

Comment: How to save the PHP AJAX value into database: link -> paste.ofcode.org/RtS52ymcejzLuPXjxgXvQb @ Punitha Subramani Yoganyaa S

Answer (score 0):

For submitting `form` elements values to action page, you have to use `name` property of the `form` element.

Add `name` property to the dropdown like,

```
<form name="stdntdetails" action="submit_stdntdetails.php" method="post">
    <select name="selectname">
        <option value="IT">Information Technology</option>
        <option value="IS">Information System</option>
        <option value="CS">Computer Science</option>
    </select>
   <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

and you can retrieve the selected value in the action page, *submit_stdntdetails.php* as

```
echo $_POST['selectname'];
```

Comment: where is the submit button??

Comment: Cool. Second error. But where is the php script to insert into the database?? I think OP also needs that

Comment: How to save the PHP AJAX value into database: link -> paste.ofcode.org/RtS52ymcejzLuPXjxgXvQb @Jenz

Comment: url: "save.php", 
 type: "get",
  data: { 
    id: 4, 
    UserID: '1234
  }, ----> In save.php you get the value of UserID and connect the database and do insert into the database.

Answer (score -2):

In the html change it to

```
<form name="stdntdetails" action="submit_stdntdetails.php" method="post">
    <select name="select">
        <option value="IT">Information Technology</option>
        <option value="IS">Information System</option>
        <option value="CS">Computer Science</option>
    </select>
<input type="submit" value="submit" /> <!-- you need a submit button to submit the form-->
</form>
```

then in the php page

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","mysql_user","mysql_pwd");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

// some code

if(isset($_POST['select'])
{
$select = $_POST['select'];

$query = "INSERT INTO table_name (col1) VALUES ('$select')";
mysql_query($query);
}

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: The query is wide open to SQL injection. Plus, mysql_query is deprecated and will be removed from PHP eventually.

Comment: WHo is the generous person who downvoted it? I hope he will dare to answer.

Comment: its after 5.5. Secondly Mysql injection happens when we use quotes in some data. His values are just IT,IS,CS.

Comment: I didn't, but I understand, hence my comment.

Comment: Having a drop down list doesn't prevent from posting anything else than the provided values.

Comment: Thats why I told you, from dropdown he is just getting IT,IS,CS.. so no case of sql injection

Comment: No, that's exactly the opposite. You can post anything, even if it's not in the list. http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/42264/is-it-possible-to-inject-values-in-a-drop-down-list